# How to programmatically access a control on a aspx page from the cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I access a control on an aspx page from the cs file in a programmatic way?

For instance, if I have a set of asp:Panel controls each with an ID named by a city (id="atlanta", id="chicago", id="pittsburgh", etc.) and then in the cs I grab a value from the database to match up to the control names what would I use?

I tried to use FindControl() as shown and it returns null.

aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="atlanta" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Panel>
```

cs file:

```
controlName = storeLocation.City.ToLower();
Panel cityPanel = (Panel)FindControl(controlName);
cityPanel.Visible = true;
```

I suppose FindControl() is really for use in cases like Repeaters or Grids where you pass in the ItemTemaplate.  In my case its just a simple content page with a content tag with a bunch of panels in it.

Comment: did you check my answer? I tried it in my machine and it seems to work. I'm curious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindControl()` isn't recursive, which may be your problem. However, there are many implementations of a recursive version, such as [this one](http://techmantium.com/recursive-findcontrol/).

If you are creating the panels dynamically and you want access to them later in the page lifecycle, you can add them all to a `Dictionary<string, Panel>` where the ID is the key.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works.  As others have noted, recursion could be taxing but the structure of the aspx page in its current state should not be a problem.  If it changes and becomes more complex this could be a concern but I don't foresee this page changing other than copy/text.

Comment: Glad it works. If you know the direct parent of all of the items you can avoid recursion, but otherwise I wouldn't worry about it. Recursion through a few levels of controls is very inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method to find controls recursively:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{

    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control child in control.GetAllControls())
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your code behind page you could do something like this if you prefix your labels:

```
IEnumerable<Control> city_controls = this.GetAllControls().Where(x => x.Id.Contains("city_"))
```

or a single control:

```
var city = this.GetAllControls().Single(x => x.Id = "atlanta");
```

Where the `this` is your ASPX code behind page.

It also works on controls such as panels, so if you want to find all controls inside a panel etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the containing control you may be able to use the `FindControl()` function of that control to find it. This method will be much faster and safer than using a recursive method.

Microsoft did not include a recursive `FindControl()` function for a reason, it will slow your page down over time as more controls get added to the page. If that doesn't work use a recursive function like other responses suggested.

Comment: I'm having issues with this too.  Trying to do a `FindControl()` on the containing content placeholder returns null as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you since the panels are nested in the *asp:Content* control.

```
    Panel cityPanel =
(Panel)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderId").FindControl(controlName);
```

Where off course, ContentPlaceHolderId is the Id of the corresponding ContentPlaceHolder in the Master page you are implementing.

Comment: I can't get this to work.
So if I have this in the aspx:

    `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphInteriorBody" Runat="Server">`
I should have this in the cs:

    `Panel concentrationPanel = (Panel)Master.FindControl("cphInteriorBody").FindControl(controlName);`

Comment: @DMase05 Yes that is the way I used and it worked for me, I'm sorry it doesn't work for you. As you said in other answer, recursion will work for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really baffled by this as I'd expect it to work as well.  Thanks anyway!